# jSoup How to Whitelist tags matching certain class patterns?

Tags: jsoup

I am using Whitelist as follows:

```
           Document doc = Jsoup.parse(urls[0], 5000);
            if (doc != null){

                Whitelist wl = Whitelist.basicWithImages();
                // wl.preserveRelativeLinks(false);
                Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(wl);
                cleanedDoc=cleaner.clean(doc);
                if (cleanedDoc != null){
                   whiteListedHtml = cleanedDoc.html();
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
           Log.d(TAG,"exception="+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Now this is so painfully close to what I would like to do except:
There are div tags whose class have "nav" or "ad" and are filling the page
with rubish.  I want to keep div tags for example but not if the class happens to have 'nav' or 'ad' appearing in it.

This makes me think about subclassing Whitelist ....
RTFM http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html  I see 
addTag(), and removeTag() (somehow removeTag() is not available but thats another issue).  What I really want to do is remove if and only if the class of the tag contains certain values in the sting such as 'ad' or 'nav'. 
The only method that looks hopeful is:

```
protected boolean isSafeTag(String tag)

Test if the supplied tag is allowed by this whitelist

Parameters:
    tag - test tag 
Returns:
    true if allowed
```

So how can I pull out the class value of this string for test?  Is there anyway to do this check without subclassing whitelist?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to remove tags like `<div class='ad'>` manually. First, add the `div` tag to your whitelist (else the cleaner will remove them)

```
 Whitelist wl = Whitelist
     .basicWithImages()
     .addTags("div");
```

After that, select all elements you want to remove and ... simply remove them ^^

```
doc
    .select("div[class=\"nav\"]")
    .forEach(e -> e.remove());
```

(you can also use wildcards - see the [selector-syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax))

Afterwards clean the document just like you did.

*Note: you can also do it the other way around - clean first, then remove*