# jSoup How to Whitelist tags matching certain class patterns?

Tags: jsoup

I am using Whitelist as follows:

```
           Document doc = Jsoup.parse(urls[0], 5000);
            if (doc != null){

                Whitelist wl = Whitelist.basicWithImages();
                // wl.preserveRelativeLinks(false);
                Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(wl);
                cleanedDoc=cleaner.clean(doc);
                if (cleanedDoc != null){
                   whiteListedHtml = cleanedDoc.html();
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
           Log.d(TAG,"exception="+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Now this is so painfully close to what I would like to do except:
There are div tags whose class have "nav" or "ad" and are filling the page
with rubish.  I want to keep div tags for example but not if the class happens to have 'nav' or 'ad' appearing in it.

This makes me think about subclassing Whitelist ....
RTFM http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html  I see 
addTag(), and removeTag() (somehow removeTag() is not available but thats another issue).  What I really want to do is remove if and only if the class of the tag contains certain values in the sting such as 'ad' or 'nav'. 
The only method that looks hopeful is:

```
protected boolean isSafeTag(String tag)

Test if the supplied tag is allowed by this whitelist

Parameters:
    tag - test tag 
Returns:
    true if allowed
```

So how can I pull out the class value of this string for test?  Is there anyway to do this check without subclassing whitelist?  Now I am trying this:

```
    protected boolean isSafeTag(String tag){
      Boolean retVal = true;
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(tag);
    if (doc.getAllElements().size()>0){
        Element e = doc.getAllElements().get(0);
        String attribute =  e.attr("class");
          if ((attribute != null) && (attribute.contains("ad") ||   attribute.contains("nav"))){
            retVal = false;
           }
       }
       if (retVal == false)
          return false
       else
          return super.isSafeTag(tag);
```

Comment: why didn't you just edit your old post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126331/jsoup-how-to-whitelist-tags-matching-certain-class-patterns?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to do this check without subclassing whitelist?

One way is to remove the unwanted divs then clean the resulting document.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String html = "<html><head></head><body><div class=\"ad\">Remove</div><p>Hello word</p><div>Don't remove</div></body></html>";

System.out.println("** BEFORE:\n" + html);
Document dirtyDoc = Jsoup.parse(html);
for (Element div : dirtyDoc.select("div.ad, div.nav")) {
    div.remove();
}

Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist //
        .basicWithImages() // your original choosen list
        .addTags("div"); // Without this line, any div will be removed

Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(whitelist);
Document cleanedDoc = cleaner.clean(dirtyDoc);

System.out.println("\n** AFTER:\n" + cleanedDoc.html());
```

#### OUTPUT

```
** BEFORE:
<html><head></head><body><div class="ad">Remove</div><p>Hello word</p><div>Don't remove</div></body></html>

** AFTER:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>Hello word</p>
  <div>
   Don't remove
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Jsoup 1.8.3**

Comment: Looks like what I want. Will div.ad find elements like <div class="abc-ad-def"/> where ad just appears somewhere in the class name? or will it only find <div class="ad"/>

Comment: @Stephen is dirtyDoc.select("div[class*="ad"] 
"))   to get all div with substring of 'ad' ?

Comment: @Stacking `dirtyDoc.select("div[class*=ad]"))` will return all divs with a class attribute containing ad. Please note that with the `*=` operator, the double quotes aren't needed around the value ad. For details, see full selector syntax here: `jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html`